# redirect to another page from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.insadmin = function () {
            $http.get('/csuv5.asmx/tadmin', {
                params: {        
                    auserid: $scope.userid,
                    bpass: $scope.pass,
                    cname: $scope.name,
                    ddesignation: $scope.designation,
                    eteam:$scope.team
                }
            })

            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.sonvinrpm = 'success';
               // $scope.userid="",
               //  $scope.pass = "",
               //  $scope.name = "",
               //  $scope.designation = "",
               //$scope.team = ""
                $location.absUrl() = 'testangu.aspx';
            });
        }
    });
        </script>
```

this is my angularjs script of my application which is working fine but the problem starts with `$location.absUrl() = 'testangu.aspx';` this line here i want to redirect the page to another page but it is not working `$scope.sonvinrpm = 'success';` the success message is showing but the page is not redirecting to another page this is the first time i am trying this so guys please do help me out

Comment: `absUrl` is a read-only method

Comment: @Maximus which method do i need to use here

Comment: which part of the URI do you want to update - domain, path, search, hash?

Comment: look i just want to refresh the whole page

Comment: just refresh with the same url?

Comment: yes i want to refresh with the same url(testangu.aspx is my page in which i am working and i want to just refresh the page after insert completed)

Comment: when you refresh the page, you'll lose all the data that come from `response`. do you realize that? maybe describe more of what you're trying to do. see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39974518/2545680) for simply reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the entire page and reset the state of your application you can use:

```
$window.location.reload();
```

This is a standard DOM method which you can access injecting the [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service.

If you want the `success` message to be shown for some time before the page is reloaded, you can wrap the code above into timeout and wait some time:

```
var timeToWait = 3000; // 3 seconds

$timeout(function() {
    $window.location.reload();
}, timeToWait);
```

Comment: I agree with you, but > $scope.sonvinrpm = 'success'; the success message is showing < will not work as he expect :(

Comment: @slackmart, yes, but it's unclear what OP wants. Maybe wrap in timeout than

Comment: Yep, it's unclear. I was thinking in `angular.module('app').run(['$http, function($http) { /*http call, set the sonvinrpm variable again*/}])` but I don't like so much that approach, BTW I wasn't heard about doing something similar using `$timeout`. Interesting..:)

Comment: yeah, if you find the approach inteteresting, you can upvote) I'm on my way to 10k :)

Comment: done!. go ahead dude!. BTW I was reading some of your contributions on medium site :) Nice stuff

Comment: @slackmart, thanks for the support, mate. In a few days I'm about to publish a big detailed article on the `Number` type (floating point) in JS that I've been working on for a month now :). Follow me to get notified.

Answer (score 0):

The `url()` in AngularJS is a **getter/setter** method. You can set it by passing the URL value as the method argument:

```
$location.url('testangu.aspx');
```

Comment: [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#absUrl) it says that it's getter only.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use windows location to meet your requirement

```
location.href = "testangu.aspx";
```

I hope it works for you